# OpenCl code in CPU but works good when run in GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, multicore

I am new to OpenCL and I tried to run my code in Nvidia GeForce GTX 680 with cuda 5.5, but for a suprise after successfully compiling my code while running it provides an error `clGetDeviceIDs(-1)` in cpu.; but it worked fine when I tried to run in GPU. The compile command I am using:

```
alias occ='g++ -I/home/software/local/opencl/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc -L/home/software/local/opencl/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/lib/x64 -lOpenCL
```

and

```
occ filename.cpp
```

The part of code I am changing from CPU to GPU is

```
clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices );
```

What should be the changes i must do to run my opencl code in multicore CPU?

Comment: You have to change the platform: NVIDIAs OpenCL implementation is only for NVIDIA **GPU**. If you want to run OpenCL on the CPU, you need an OpenCL implementation from AMD or Intel (they support **CPU**). It may be a bit fiddly to install two OpenCL implementations in parallel (the order of the platforms obtained by `clGetPlatformID` may change), but it is possible.

Comment: @Macro13: thanks for your suggestions. I had tried so many things but failed now i know the solution.